# Release memory of an unmanaged code without dispose method

Tags: c#, .net, clr, pdfium

I have installed a NuGet package in my C# project which used unmanaged code. I have created an object of a sealed class. which doesn't have a dispose method defined in the class. How do I release the unmanaged memory? 
I can see that my memory usage is incrementing time by time and my application is getting kicked out.
My code is

```
 var bitmap = new PDFiumBitmap(100, 100, true);
```

I tried `((IDisposable)bitmap).Dispose();`  It is not working.

Here PDFiumBitmap is an unmanaged object. I want to release the memory.
PDFiumBitmap gives me back a handle. Which looks like a pointer
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kE0Sk.png)

Comment: set `bitmap` to `null`

Comment: If you set to null it won't release the unmanaged memory

Comment: Whoever wrote `PDFiumBitmap` is responsible for managing the resources it uses. You say *"I  tried `((IDisposable)bitmap).Dispose()`; It is not working"*. What do you mean? Did it compile, or did it not change the behavior you believe you are seeing? How are you measuring memory usage? What do you mean by *"my application is getting kicked out."*?

Comment: This class https://github.com/Zubastic/PDFiumSharp/blob/master/PDFiumSharp/PDFiumBitmap.cs has a Dispose method. Are you sure it's not Disposable?

Comment: I am using it from nuget package. That package doesn't contain a dispose method

Comment: Packages don't have methods. Did your call to `((IDisposable)bitmap).Dispose();` compile?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no way to go, you could try put `GC.collect()` where you want to release memory (Not very recommend).